# How to calculate cost of reading gcp Pub/Sub messages from external service

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a service that run on AWS

The service suppose to read messages from GCP Pub/Sub

How to calculate the cost of reading messages between the two above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several cost to consider:

- [PubSub cost](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/pricing) based on the volume of the messages
- The [internet egress cost](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/network-pricing) because you send the data to AWS through internet
- the AWS cost for the processing.

Comment: The second option is what I looking for.
Thanks.